# Sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{-1^{i-1}}{2i-1} $ in a different order

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm supposed to sum this infinite series in a different order so that the limit appears to be .5. I need to  to add the first k positive terms, and subtract the first l negative terms, so that the result is within $\pm  .05 $ of $.5$ (between .45 and .55), $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{-1^{i-1}}{2i-1} $$ 
How do I set it up to add the positive terms, and subtract the negative?

Comment: Set up one list $A=1,1/5,1/9,1/13,...$ and another list $B=1/3,1/7,1/11,...$.  Start with $1$ from $A$. Subtract $1/3,1/7,...$ until it is less than 0.5  Now add $1/5,1/9,...$ until it is more than 0.5.  When it is more than 0.5, subtract the next B number.  And so on.

Comment: @Nosrati this is not a duplicate.  It is about conditionally convergent series giving any number if you shuffle it.

Answer (score 0):

$$-1=i^2$$

So, the sum $$=\dfrac i2\ln\dfrac{1+i}{1-i}$$

Comment: can you elaborate? why did you do any of that?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.  It is about conditionally convergent series giving any answer you like when you shuffle it.

Comment: @Empy2, Check that I've not marked the post as duplicate

Comment: Whoops sorry, lab